# Any notable Telekinesis accessible-only items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Or is it just meant for juggling my used dragon claws?

Comment: I'm marking an answer here, but if someone comes along with an item that can only be accessed via telekinesis I will switch it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eagle Eye perk + The Illusion Silent Casting perk + Telekinesis will let you scope out a room for expensive items to yoink. Aside from that, there's really nothing exclusive to Telekinesis. ;'<

Comment: Interesting.  But it saddens me that the developers didn't hide a Daedric Axe of Awesomeness somewhere where I had to use my mind/magic to get it.

Comment: @Killith there is always updates and expansion packs. So hopefully there's still a chance.